# SELECT строк пока сумма значений поля не станет равно 0

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица поступления товаров. С полем qty, price
Известно количество остатков товара на складе - например 3.
Нужно выбрать все строки из таблицы поступления с общим количеством штук 3. Чтобы получить массив цен.
К примеру, 
Есть два поступления: первое значения qty = 4, price 10, и второе приход qty = 2, price - 5. Нужно получить в результате запроса две строки qty - 1, price - 10 и вторую строку qty - 2, price - 5. Как написать такой запрос?

Comment: Запрос получится нетривиальный и плохо сопровождаемый. Напишите лучше хранимую процедуру с курсором внутри - она как раз будет простейшая и вполне прозрачная.

Comment: хранимую процедуру с курсором внутри - а пример можно? А то ни разу не делал процедуры.

Comment: begin
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 4; 
        WHILE i>0 DO 
        SELECT `id`, `arrival_id`, `product_specification_id`, `currency_id`, `qty`, `cost`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `arrival_product` WHERE `product_specification_id` = 4;
        SET i=i-2; 
        END WHILE;
  end дошел до такой процедуры. вопрос только как уменьшать на qty из запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(goodname VARCHAR(32), amount INT)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (@qty INT, @price DECIMAL) ENGINE Memory;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT qty, price 
                           FROM goods 
                           WHERE name=goodname 
                           ORDER BY incomedate DESC;
    SET @amount=0;
    SET @done=0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @done=1;
    OPEN cur;
    cycle: REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO @qty, @price;
        IF @done=1 THEN LEAVE cycle;
        IF @amount+@qty>=amount then
            INSERT INTO temp(qty,price) SELECT  amount-@amount, @price;
            SET @done=1;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO temp(qty,price) SELECT  @qty, @price;
            SET @amount=@amount+@qty;
        END IF;
    UNTIL @done=1 END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cur;
    SELECT * FROM temp;
    DROP TABLE temp;
END;
```

PS. Схематично != готовый код - отладка needed...

Comment: ща буду пробовать.

Comment: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'AS
BEGIN

Comment: почитал мануалы нигде AS вроде не используют

Comment: убрал AS теперь #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '@qty INT, @cost DECIMAL) ENGINE Memory' на строке 3

Comment: исправил Ваш ответ до протестированной процедуры на основании вашей схемы.